# node:events:371 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: read EFAULT

Tags: node.js, express

I've been getting this error and have tried reinstalling node/vscode already to no avail. This happens maybe 30% of the time after I save my changes in vscode and it ALWAYS crashes my node server.

Nodemon doesn't turn my server back on and it gets really tedious when trying to code. Does anyone have any solutions to this problem?

I'm running on a Macbook Air 2020 with a M1 chip if that makes a difference.

(Using express / nodejs ) node v16.6.0

I've tried killall node, I've tried changing port number. same errors

````
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read EFAULT
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -14,
  code: 'EFAULT',
  syscall: 'read'
}```
````

Comment: which version of node do you use?

Comment: It happens in node 16.3.0 :/